# Django custom paginator fails to catch non integer value

Tags: django

I want to use my own `Paginator` in view based on `ListView`. The need for custom `Paginator` is coming from two user errors I want to catch: too big number and no number.

There is no problem in catching the first issue with `EmptyPage` error. What I have problem with is no number error - e.g. `?page=k`

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/paginator/#exceptions) I would assume this can be achieved with `PageNotAnInteger`, or both with `InvalidPage`. So this is what I did:

```
class SafePaginator(Paginator):
    def validate_number(self, number):
        try:
            return super(SafePaginator, self).validate_number(number)
        except InvalidPage:
            return 1
```

Unfortunately, still when I test `?page=k` option I'm getting error:

> Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int.

`?page=last` is working correctly

This seems to be coming from `ListView` `paginate_queryset` as you can see on [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L67)

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
        """Paginate the queryset, if needed."""
        paginator = self.get_paginator(
            queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
            allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
        page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg
        page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1
        try:
            page_number = int(page)
        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            else:
                raise Http404(_('Page is not “last”, nor can it be converted to an int.'))
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
        except InvalidPage as e:
            raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
                'page_number': page_number,
                'message': str(e)
            })
```

But shouldn't it be called after `valid_number` check? Also, I've tried adding `except ValueError`, which also doesn't help.

Is there any other way I should catch this error?

Answer (score 1):

> But shouldn't it be called after valid_number check? Also, I've tried adding except ValueError, which also doesn't help.

**No**, since as you can see, it tries to convert this with `int(page)`. If *that* fails, it will raise a `ValueError` and check for `'last'`. So `pagiantor.page(page_number)` is *never* performed when `int(page)` fails, and `page` is not `'last'`.

Adding an `except ValueError` will not help either, since again, control is *never* passed to the `.page()` method, and hence to the `validate_number()` method.

A solution might be to simply replace the value with `1`, for example:

```
from django.http import Http404

class MyListView(ListView):
    # …

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
        try:
            return super().paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size)
        except Http404:
            paginator = self.get_paginator(
                queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
                allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
            try:
                page = paginator.page(1)
                return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
            except InvalidPage as e:
                raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
                    'page_number': page_number,
                    'message': str(e)
                })
```